# Speed of video incorrect; Beamer

Tags: video

I am new to LaTeX and I am facing a problem when trying to insert a video in my `beamer` presentation. I am using MiKTeX together with Texcenter. The package I use is `media9` and here is the code I use to insert the video:

```
\includemedia[
width=0.95\linewidth,
height=0.95\linewidth,
activate=pageopen,
passcontext,
addresource=video_presentation.mp4,
flashvars={source=video_presentation.mp4}
]{}{VPlayer.swf}
```

The problem I have is that this video is much faster than it truly is when using for example VLC software.

I did not find any solution while looking at the `media9` package pdf (for example, no "rate" option as for media15 that is not to use now if I get it right) or on the internet but I may have missed the information.

Hoping that some of you have an idea of what is happening,
Thank you very much for trying to help and my apology for my English mistakes,
Best.